# How to deal with transfer encoding in Python?

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests, transfer-encoding

I am working on an analytic API for small ML project. I have created an endpoint, which uses Flask's `stream_with_context` function like in the example below:

```
def post():
       # some logic
       [...]

        try:
            res = get_data_from_elastic()

            def generate():
                for hit in res:
                    resp_dict = {
                        "timestamp": hit.timestamp,
                        "user_id": hit.user_id,
                        "node_id": hit.node_id,
                        "loc": hit.loc,
                        "is_target": hit.is_target
                    }
                    yield json.dumps(resp_dict) + '\n'

            return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

        # except:
           # some exception handling
```

It's not an exact extract from my code, but the generator works the same. I use Python requests to connect to the API, with the following code:

```
response = requests.post(analytic_api_url, 
                         headers={'Authorization': token}, 
                         data={'since': since,'till': till})
```

When I connect to the API and download small amounts of data at once, everything works fine. Unfortunately, when I try to download bigger amount of data at once, I am getting the following error:

`ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))`

As the error is about `chunked encoding`, I've checked things like setting `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header in the server's response, I've also tried using `stream=True` parameter from the `requests` library - none of these solutions worked.
How should I deal with this problem? Should I explicitly set some other `Transfer-Encoding` header, or create another generator for my API?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace from your flask app?

Comment: Yup. The answer came as soon as I took a look at this stacktrace once more :) 
I think I'll left this comment for the people that stumble upon this problem in the future: 

`"node_id": node_details.id`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' ` - some of the documents I've tried to iterate over was not complete (due to the way I collected this data). So, it seems like the point is to always take care of the integrity of the data.

Comment: You can edit your question and add your solution

Answer (score 0):

I'll left this comment for the people that stumble upon this problem in the future:
`"node_id": node_details.id AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`
some of the documents I've tried to iterate over were not complete (due to the way I collected this data). So, it seems like the point is to always take care of the integrity of the data.